# jsp is not reachable

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a simple web application that contains:

- a web service:

  ```
  @Path("hello") public class Hello {
    @GET public String hello() { return "Hello"; }
  }
  ```
- in the webapp folder, a login.jsp file that says hello

I can access the former on `http://my-ip:8080/my-app/hello` but I can't access the latter on `http://my-ip:8080/my-app/login.jsp`.

When opening the second address, the server throws an exception:

> failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://my-ip:8080/my-app/login.jsp

Am I missing anything obvious here?

I'm using Wildfly 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {}
```

that was already bound to the root path so the login.jsp file, also in the root path, was ignored. Changing the above to `@ApplicationPath("rest")` solved the issue.